# function ccDrawPoly not found in cocos2d - how do I draw a polygon?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I upgraded to Cocos2D v 3. ccDrawPoly is no longer a function. How do I draw a polygon?

ccDrawingPrimities.m, where the function was, no longer exists.

Comment: it's not documented but there are custom GL wrapper methods in v3, check out how CCSprite's draw (or visit) method is implemented to find those methods.

Comment: I tried- (void)draw:(CCRenderer *)renderer transform:(const GLKMatrix4 *)transform {
    [self drawDot:CGPointMake(200, 200) radius:100 color:[CCColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0]];, the code runs (breakpoint hits) but I see nothing.